# SQL issue in populating a Data extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

Could anyone help identify why this SQL won't populate to a data extension:

```
    Select l.Id 
, l.Email 
, l.FirstName
 , l.LastName
 , l.MC_Lead_Mobile_Phone__c as MobilePhone 
, l.Salutation
 , e.Confirmation_only_preference__c as ChannelPreference
 From ENT.Lead_Salesforce l Join ENT.Event_Salesforce e On l.Id = e.Id
```

When the following will to a copy of the same data extension?

```
Select l.Id
    , l.Email
    , l.FirstName
    , l.LastName
    , l.MC_Lead_Mobile_Phone__c as MobilePhone
    , l.Salutation
    , e.Confirmation_only_preference__c as ChannelPreference
    , e.AppointmentCount
From ENT.Lead_Salesforce l 
    Inner Join 
        (
        Select e.Confirmation_only_preference__c, l.Id, Count(0) as AppointmentCount
        FROM ENT.Event_Salesforce e
            INNER JOIN ENT.Lead_Salesforce l
                ON e.WhoId = l.Id
        WHERE
            CONVERT(date, e.ActivityDate) = Convert(date, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()))
            /*AND Convert(date, e.CreatedDate) != Convert(date, GETDATE())*/
            AND l.Is_Holiday_Maker__c = 0
            AND e.Appointment_Status__c = 'Confirmed'
            AND ISNULL(l.Email, '') != ''
            AND ISNULL(l.ConvertedContactId, '') = ''
            AND e.Confirmation_only_preference__c IN ('SMS', 'Email')
        GROUP BY
            e.Confirmation_only_preference__c, l.Id ) e
            On l.Id = e.Id
```

I've been fiddling with it for some time, and am wondering if it's perhaps because it's a large data set, although I'm not getting any errors or time out messages.

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is your join is incorrect how is lead.id = event.id should this be joined on a different field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're trying to join 2 CRM objects by the unique identifier for both - this will never work as they're both universally unique.

Based on the second query bringing back something (even though it's badly put together), I'm guessing what you want is:

```
SELECT l.[Id], 
l.[Email], 
l.[FirstName],
l.[LastName],
l.[MC_Lead_Mobile_Phone__c] as [MobilePhone],
l.[Salutation],
e.[Confirmation_only_preference__c] as [ChannelPreference]
FROM ENT.Lead_Salesforce l INNER JOIN ENT.Event_Salesforce e On l.[Id] = e.[WhoId]
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. It worked, and now I know I know nothing, so that's also helpful.